# mic access into my browser

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am testing the annyang library for the voice command.

Unfortunately I am facing a problem that it works but the browser (chrome) only allows the listening for about 5 secs, then it asks for me to allow/deny the mic again.
(the allow is not saving in the chrome/manage exceptions setting).

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can experience this behavior on the annyang official site, if you remove the SSL protocol (which is the default):

http://www.talater.com/annyang/

The reason for this is that Chrome only saves audio permission preferences for sites running on SSL. Annyang appears to close the audio context after a period of time if it isn't being used (presumably a performance thing).

Your two options are to:

- Add SSL to your site using the library
- File a bug report, because it should only attempt to make a connection to the audio context once

Comment: Thanks for your reply, could you explain (give me a link) how to ass SSL to your site?

Comment: @user1444393 You'll need to Google that, as it differs depending on how you host your site